# Improving on dynamic imports

Tags: javascript, import

I was recently using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) in an app with localization. In order to set the locale and get appropriate date/time formats, you use `moment.locale('foo')`. However, this isn't enough on its own; you first need to import the locale you need via `import 'moment/locale/foo'`.

Now say the client wants the ability to dynamically switch languages. You have a dilemma: either you import all the supported languages up front, or you lazy-load by dynamically importing.

```
import('moment/locale/' + languageCode);
moment.locale(languageCode);
```

Something about dynamically importing in a compiled environment feels wrong to me ([also see here](https://blog.mgechev.com/2019/05/11/dynamic-imports-javascript/)), but then as my colleague noted, so does importing a bunch of unnecessary stuff up front.

Is there a best practice here?

Comment: I think lazy loading is the preferred method here because the performance impact will only apply to users who change the language.